# Cannot write NFC on Android

Tags: android, nfc, payment

```
public boolean writeTag(Tag tag, NdefMessage message) {
    int size = message.toByteArray().length;

    try {
        Ndef ndef = Ndef.get(tag);
        if (ndef != null) {
            ndef.connect();
            if (!ndef.isWritable()) {
                return false;
            }
            if (ndef.getMaxSize() < size) {
                return false;
            }
            ndef.writeNdefMessage(message);
            return true;
        } else {
            NdefFormatable format = NdefFormatable.get(tag);
            if (format != null) {
                try {
                    format.connect();
                    format.format(message);
                    return true;
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    return false;
                }
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

When I debug, I got:

```
this = {NFCWrite@9357} 
tag = {Tag@9386} "TAG: Tech [android.nfc.tech.IsoDep, android.nfc.tech.NfcA]"
message = {NdefMessage@9417} "NdefMessage [NdefRecord tnf=2 type=6A7A6A736A64646A64 payload=6A7A6A736A64646A64]"
size = 21
ndef = null
format = null

mTechStringList = {String[2]@9587} 
 0 = "android.nfc.tech.IsoDep"
 1 = "android.nfc.tech.NfcA"
```

I so wonder why

- ndef allways return null
- format always return null

So that, ndef.connect() cannot connect.
and then I use NdefFormatable  for format get tage
but still get null too.

Answer (score 0):

Not all NFC Tags support the Ndef data format. Some Tags can support it using propitiatory encoding methods.

As your Tag does not list `android.nfc.tech.Ndef` or `android.nfc.tech.NdefFormatable` as supported `Tech` types, this Tag **cannot support storing Ndef** data using the NFC standards

(As you don't specify the Tag make and model it is impossible if it could support Ndef using a propitiatory encoding methods, but this might not help much as a lot of other readers would not read a propitiatory encoded Tag anyway)

**update:**

The Tag supports two Tag Techs `IsoDep` and `NfcA` both of these have a `transceive` method to send commands to the Tag with `IsoDep`
(ISO 14443-4) being a higher level protocol on top of `NfcA`

It is likely that you will be able to send commands to read and possibly write to the Tag, but exactly how to do this depends on the make and model of the Tag, as you don't specify the make and model of the Tag it is impossible to find the datasheet for the Tag to identify what these commands are.

Comment: So do you have any suggestion to make us write and ready tag NFC ?
Now we are finding solution for read and write tage for NFC.

Comment: Added an update, but the question is lacking information to answer further.

Comment: Process: com.example.peng.nfcreadwrite, PID: 23272
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.nfc.tech.Ndef.connect()' on a null object reference

I got error like this.

Comment: Hello sir, could you share me some solutions about write tag or how to create app payment between phone device and phone device by using NFC.  I so stuck on cannot write tag and also when get tag like these: